MGLTools Segmentation Fault
I'm currently working as an intern for computational chemistry. One of the applications that we need is MGLTools which I installed using this website:
https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/mgltools/README.html
I followed all of the instructions but it displays this error whenever I type the command 'adt'
Run ADT from  /home/cobe/mamba/envs/mgl/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools
Segmentation fault

I cannot find solutions to this error and have consulted my peers for this and this was also the first time they have encountered the error. I have little experience in coding and programming (only Python) and some have suggested to use GDB to debug the error, however I am not knowledgeable in this.
Please let me know what can you suggest to fix this. Thank you!
Reinstalled Ubuntu and mamba.

If the segmentation fault generated a core dump, you may be able to get more information by loading it into gdb using gdb -c core and then using the bt (backtrace) command - however it's unlikely that you will learn much since there almost certainly won't be any debug symbols available. See A big core dump appeared in my home folder - what is it and how can I delete it? for more background.
